# unable to locate android.bat

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to setup a new development enviroment in phonegap.

Here is how my path variable setup looks in windows:

```
C:\Users\Mrinal\AppData\Roaming\npm;
C:\android\development\sdk\platform-tools;
C:\android\development\sdk\tools;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin;
C:\ant\bin
```

Now in the third line, actually there is no such directory called tools at that path.
Rest works.

Now when i do this in command prompt:

```
c:\android\phonegap\lib\android\bin>create
```

I get this

```
Cannot locate android.bat using the PATH environment variable.
Retry after adding directory containing android.bat to the PATH variable.
Remember to open a new command window after updating the PATH variable.
Visit http://developer.android.com if you need to install the Android SDK.
```

I made a search in the whole development directory for this android.bat file but can't find it.
Where i am going wrong here?

Comment: is the Android SDK updated by the SDK manager?

Comment: i just downloaded and installed it a few mins back from deverlopers.android.com

Answer (score 4):

Android.bat is under your user directory:

```
C:\Users\<Your_UserName>\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools
```

Answer (score 1):

Right click on My Computers and open Properties.
In Windows Vista or 7 Go to Advanced System Settings Else go to next step
Go To Advanced Tab and click on Envionment Varibales button.
Select 'Path' in 'System Variables' press 'Edit' and Add 'c:\\adt-bundle-windows.......\sdk\tools'